# What is causing Java program to treat the two ResultSet.getString() methods differently?

Tags: java, resultset

If "FirstName" and index 1 refer to the same column in a query, and `rs` is a `ResultSet`, why would

```
if(rs.getString("FirstName")!=null) fullName = rs.getString("FirstName");
```

and

```
if(rs.getString(1)!=null) fullName = rs.getString(1);
```

behave differently?

According to the Java docs, using either the `columnIndex` or the `columnLabel`
both return the value of the designated column.

I'm running into a weird problem when I use the `columnIndex` instead of the `columnLabel`, for some reason, after the jsp has been running for a few hours/days then `if(rs.getString(1)!=null)` evaluates to true even when the String is `null`. When I use the `columnLabel` instead, the problem doesn't happen. Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

### Extra background info

The program runs in Tomcat. We updated Tomcat, the JVM, and our database driver on the same day, and this started happening. If we reload the app in Tomcat, it starts working correctly, at least for a few hours. We switched back to the old database driver and the problem continues, so we have ruled out the database driver.

Comment: Probably because they don't refer to the same column... Have you tried printing the name of the column? (I'm assuming you know that columns are numbered from 1 and not 0)

Comment: They definitely refer to the same column, as the code works correctly, for a few hours at least.

Comment: Can you add your complete SQL query ?

Comment: SELECT FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName FROM Users WHERE Users.userID= 'csr'

This is just a small example, we've seen it happening in multiple queries across different jsp's

Comment: `even when the String is null` maybe this is not true?
I assume your code looks like rs.getString(1) or rs.getString("asdf") across whole function. I'd suggest to try using rs.getString(1) and rs.getString("asdf") near each other to catch it.
Also old database driver could have this bug anyway, I believe it should not be ruled out yet.

Comment: Curious code. Why not just `fullName = rs.getString("FirstName");`, without the `if`? That way it will be either `null` or the column value. What other value could you want?

Comment: @EJP
We have worked around the problem by always using `rs.getString("FirstName")`. We are just trying to figure out why we have the problem when using columnIndex since it is a mystery. We haven't seen any other info online with people having this same problem, so we thought we would ask.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved it. We decided to try a different SQL driver (we were using a Microsoft driver before, we switched to JTDS) and all problems have gone away.

So I'm guessing the Microsoft driver was returning the string "null" when it should have been returning `null`.

So to answer the question, the `ResultSet.getString()` method was probably behaving correctly all along, but the SQL driver was returning bad data.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.getString(1)` returns the data for the first column in your SQL query executed (by the `preparedStatement`), it need NOT be the `FirstName`, you need to cross check that your SQL query in `preparedStatement` is as follows:

```
SELECT FirstName from X;//you might add where conditions
```

Comment: I've checked to make sure that the first column is the same as FirstName. What is so weird about this is that it will work for a few hours, and then randomly stop working correctly when we use the columnIndex. Using the columnName always works right. I want to understand why.

Comment: After few hours what happens ? Any exceptions ? Can you add those to the question ?

Comment: There are no exceptions, it just starts returning the String "null" instead of the actual null value. So the fullName becomes the String "null".

Comment: if you're getting `"null"`, then you have either inserted `"null"` into the database or you are wrapping a null as a string somewhere. Given it's right from the resultset, I'm going to go with the first, but how did you print the string to determine it was `"null"` and not `null`?

Comment: @Rogue The `fullName` variable is initially set to "" (empty string). If the ResultSet is not `null`, `fullName` is set to equal the ResultSet value. The database doesn't have "null" as a String, but somehow it is being returned _only_ when we use the columnIndex. So the `fullName` should always be blank String, or a legit value from the database. It is so strange.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> it just starts returning the String "null" instead of the actual null value. So the fullName becomes the String "null".

In other words the problem is different from what is stated in your question. `null` and `"null"` aren't the same thing, so there is no reason for `rs.getString(1) == null` to return `true` if the actual value is `"null"`.

I would say you probably have `"null"` in your database somewhere. Check. Or else you are using `String.valueOf(null)` somewhere in your code, possibly indirectly, e.g. via `println(null)`, which calls it, so the output is `"null"`.

Comment: Why would it work correctly when using rs.getString("FirstName") instead, or when the app is reloaded? That is my main question.

Comment: *Does* it work? The confusion I mention raises doubt as to the quality of your evidence.

Comment: Believe me, we have tested and verified, and tested again and again, because this is such a mystery. It always works correctly if we use the columnName in the getString() method. It works for a few hours when we use the columnIndex, and then starts returning "null" strings seemingly out of the blue. After we reload the app, it is good again.